Creating a Dataflow job from flex template doesn't allow to choose G2 machine type
I'm trying to run a Dataflow job using the Google Cloud Console but there isn't the G2 machine type option.
Say that I can specify the G2 machine type, and run the job using gcloud command line in the terminal specifying:
--worker-machine-type g2-standard-4
So maybe Google still doesn't add this machine type for flex templates in the Cloud console Web UI
Choose machine type G2

not sure if it helps, but I faced almost similar situation in newly announced GCP region , I wasn't able to see the region in Cloudbuild UI but I can see and use that region via REST API.
